# What's about N. M. Katz' "over-world" of exp. sums?

Tags: nt.number-theory, ag.algebraic-geometry

Having just read in N. M. Katz' [beautiful old survey](http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1990-23-02/S0273-0979-1990-15922-1/S0273-0979-1990-15922-1.pdf) on exponential sums a d differential eq.s, I wonder what became out of his question (on p. 297 - 300) on a "general conceptual framework in which to think about the variations with p of exponential sums on arbitrary schemes of finite type over Z", which he calls "over-world"?

Edit/repost: [This new review](http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/0000-000-00/S0273-0979-2013-01412-5/S0273-0979-2013-01412-5.pdf) about N.M. Katz's amazing work on equidistribution themes mentionst the theme above too, taken as occasion to repost the question...

Comment: Dear Thomas, Thank you very much for the link to this fantastic survey, which I hadn't seen before.  I have pondered this *over-world* from time-to-time (without knowing Katz's name for it), but I don't think that much is known systematically at the moment.  I have recently been talking a bit with an analytic number-theorist who is thinking very hard about concrete questions on exponential sums and their behaviour as $p$ varies (and of course this is a very deep subject that many analytic number theorists have and are thinking very hard about).  He explained some phenomena and conjectures ...

Comment: ... to me that are very striking, and which are (perhaps) some kind of analogue for Katz's *overworld* of the theory of $L$-functions for motives.  (Patterson's name is one which came up; one paper I know of is his joint paper with Livne on *First moments of cubic exponential sums*.)  I wish I understood more; I hope to learn more about it over the next few months.  Best wishes, Matthew  P.S.  The analytic number theorists don't (yet, and maybe with a couple of exceptions) think in Katz's geometric terms, but one can fantasize that their explicit classical-sounding statements and ...

Comment: ... conjectures have underlying geometric formulations, just as Weil's conjectures (and Sato--Tate etc.) have classical interpretations and consequences (some of which were known before the underlying theoretical interpretations were found). 

Comment: Dear Matthew, many thanks for the hint to Patterson/Livné's article and maybe motivic analogues!